# QHelpSearchEngine issue to show the QHelpSearchResultWidget data

Tags: qt

Hi Can any one explain me how the 'typed text' in QHelpSearchQueryWidget gets parsed and resulting HTML links gets displayed onto the QHelpSearchResultWidget.

i am using the QtHelpEngine for my application. The HTMLs as mentioned in .qhp , are showing in mi TOC and index tabs. BUT the search tab , where i included the QHelpSearchQueryWidget , and QHelpSearchResultWidget does not work.
i have tested the .qhc file in assistant , and , when i type like "all" in QHelpSearchQueryWidget it shows me the links in QHelpSearchResultWidget . But the same .qhc when used in code in my application does show show any result in QHelpSearchResultWidget.

This is the slot method i have written to , capture the entered text in QHelpSearchQueryWidget i.e "all" , and set this to QHelpSearchEngine.
and expecting the count >0 , and QHelpSearchResultWidget to be updated with related HTML links where the word "all" exists.

```
 void CHelpSearchWidgetSample::slotSearch() const
    {
    QList<QHelpSearchQuery> queries = m_searchEngine->queryWidget()->query();
    foreach (const QHelpSearchQuery &query, queries)
    {

foreach (QString word, query.wordList)
qDebug()<<"word :"<<word; // (O/P : "all")
}
m_searchEngine->search(queries);
qDebug()<<"Hit cnt : "<<m_searchEngine->hitCount(); // O/P : Hit cnt :0
}
```

please guide me to solve this issue.